# ASP.NET access denied error when running Oracle stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I have an ASP.NET website where I run an Oracle stored procedure in the following way:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(_CRSConnectionString))
{
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SCHEMA" + ".PROC"))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("curs", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
        command.Parameters.Add("p", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = p;

        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }

    connection.Close();
}

return ds;
```

This works fine on the server until the following line is added to the `web.config` file:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="user" password="password"/>
```

Now when I try to run the stored procedure, I get the following error:

[Oracle error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlnKf.jpg)

We gave permissions to the account in the identity tag to the database so that we can even log into the database with this username but still no luck.

Any ideas?